# Watching Edittext changes in view layer (MVVM Architecture)

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2

I'm new to MVVM architecture so please correct me wherever you think i'm doing wrong.

I want to implement search query to a server in my app. I need to watch for edittext text changes and as a good approach I wanted to do this (borrowed from androidhive):

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(inputSearch)
            .skipInitialValue()
            .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(searchContactsTextWatcher()))
```

the question is : does placing this in view layer(Activity or Fragment) break mvvm pattern? should I place it in viewmodel? 
at first, wanted to watch for changes in viewmodel but I didn't know how can I have `debounce` with  livedata + databinding.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend having context references in the ViewModel, why not use the android `TextWatcher` and delegate the action to the ViewModel where you can then use RxJava.

Comment: may you explain more please?